# How to add a CASE column to SQLAlchemy output?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

So far I've got basically the following:

```
MyTable.query
    .join(…)
    .filter(…)
```

The `filter` has a complicated case insensitive prefix check:

```
or_(*[MyTable.name.ilike("{}%".format(prefix)) for prefix in prefixes])
```

Now I have to *retrieve* the matching prefix in the result. In pseudo-SQL:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN strpos(lower(my_table.foo), 'prefix1') = 0 THEN 'prefix1'
           WHEN …
       END AS prefix
 WHERE prefix IS NOT NULL;
```

The [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) demonstrates how to use `CASE` within `WHERE`, which seems like a strange edge case, and not how to use it to get a new column based on an existing one.

The goal is to avoid duplicating the logic and prefix names anywhere.

Comment: Are you perhaps confused by how to add entities/columns to your query, because you're using the `Model.query` shorthand for `session.query(Model)`?

Answer (score 3):

You know that case is an expression. You can use it in any place where SQL allows it, and link to docs you have provided show how to construct the case expression.

```
from sqlalchemy import case, literal
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query

q = Query(case([
    (literal(1) == literal(1), True),
], else_ = False))

print(q)

SELECT CASE WHEN (:param_1 = :param_2) THEN :param_3 ELSE :param_4 END AS anon_1
```